# Как правильно выделять память? Или учимся использовать sizeof

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, sizeof

Дoбpый вeчep!

Как вы, наверное, знаете, структура выделения памяти такова

```
struct I * qw = (struct I *)malloc(sizeof(struct I));
```

Однако не раз мне писали, что так лучше не писать, т.к. вместо *struct I*  можно написать саму структуру (qw).

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: P.S. Не стал приводить пример своего виденья, т.к. это буду читать не только я, и после может создать кашу в голове у новичка

Comment: `struct I * qw = (__typeof__(qw))malloc(sizeof(*qw));` -- если хочется через саму переменную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выделения памяти под один объект

```
qw = malloc(sizeof *qw);
qw = calloc(1, sizeof *qw);
```

Для выделения памяти под массив

```
qw = malloc(n * sizeof *qw);
qw = calloc(n, sizeof *qw);
```

Никаких упоминаний имен типов.

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я и искал

Comment: а приведение типов никак через qw нельзя указать?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG В C это приведение не нужно, компилируется без него. В С++ оно нужно, но зачем вам в С++ `malloc`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо
Я использовал его в С
Просто для удобства, но видимо действительно проще отказаться от него